# Is there any performance or any other issues if I use a generic setter method in place of multiple setter methods in POJO or this is a bad practice?

Tags: java

I want to use a generic setter method which will take Object as argument and inside the setter I'll set the value of the property. For example, in place of

```
public class Student {
    private Long id; 
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I want to use this :

```
public class Student {
    private Long id; 
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setValues(Object propertyValue) {
        if(propertyValue instanceof Long){
            this.id = (Long) propertyValue;
        }else if(propertyValue instanceof String){
            this.name = (String) propertyValue;
        }else if(propertyValue instanceof Integer){
            this.age = (Integer) propertyValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In my POJO, all the property have unique type (No duplicate type for multiple properties).

Comment: Performance will be trivially impacted, `instanceof`checks are not particularly resource intensive.  However, I'd caution against that from a maintenance perspective.  The code would be very opaque and brittle.  What if Student gets a `private String address` property?

Comment: What happens when you have multiple properties of the same type?  (You may not *now*, but why design a system where you *can't*?)  This seems to have "bad idea" written all over it.  You're saving a few keystrokes (are you even, though?) and sacrificing stability, readability, and supportability.  Keystrokes are the easy part.  Don't focus all of your efforts on saving those.

Comment: Furthermore, you increase your feedback loop. If you passed in a date, you would find it out only during runtime, while when using normal setters it would be a compilation error. And actually, your date would be ignored, which means that program might be failing silently, and that kind of bugs are usually very difficult to find later. And of course you lose code autocompletion.

Comment: If you use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse) you can let the IDE create your getter/setter all at once with 2 mouse click.

Comment: When you’re writing code for other developers to use, how are they supposed to know what objects they can pass to your generalized method?  To be honest, a method with no obvious semantics is a nightmare for developers.

Answer (score 1):

For one, casting should always be avoided.

Second it's slower than having setters (no need to check instanceof)

Third it's even taking up more memory! You use 10 lines to replace 3 setters which would require only 9 lines :P

Fourth it's very ugly! But hey, that's just my opinion

Fifth it's not flexible, if you add anything to your pojo, you have to carefully add the check or maybe even revert to setters anyway